# php does not execute a well formed posqtgresql sentence

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

i have this code:

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=dbbase user=postgres password=postgres") or die('Connection error: ' . pg_last_error());
$qstation ="SELECT id FROM st WHERE string ='".$string."'";
$rstation = pg_query($dbconn,$qstation) or die('Query error: ' . pg_last_error());

echo $qstation;
```

this shows me

```
SELECT id FROM st WHERE string='A_AA_00_00_A'
```

if i execute it on pgadmin3, it returns me the result.

but if i try to do

```
print_r(pg_fetch_array($rstation, null, PGSQL_ASSOC));
```

i have no erros and print_r() does not return me anything.

if i change the $string variable with 'A_AA_00_00_A'

```
$qstation ="SELECT id FROM st WHERE string='A_AA_00_00_A'";
```

the sentence executes right and print_r() returns data

```
Array ( [id] => 10 )
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I would try: `$qstation ='SELECT "id" FROM "st" WHERE "string"=\''.$string.'\'';` in order to be sure the column/table names are not the problem

Comment: Really should be using parameterized statements here, though I see no reason to think that's the problem in this specific case. Use PDO, or `pg_query_params`. See http://bobby-tables.com/, "SQL injection".

Comment: @RoyalBg i have the same bad result.

Comment: @CraigRinger i will prove your recommendation

Comment: Also, look at the PostgreSQL server error log, see if (a) the statement was sent to the server at all, and (b) if it reports an error in the statement.

Comment: @CraigRinger good advice. only i looked apache log. the problem was in the $string variable.there was more charecters than i tought (something rare).i solved it with substr(). thank you

Answer (score 1):

You really should be using parameterized statements here, though I see no reason to think that's the problem in this specific case. Use PDO, or `pg_query_params`. See http://bobby-tables.com, google "SQL injection", [PHP manual on SQL injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

In a case like this you really need to look at the PostgreSQL server error logs to determine whether the query is reaching PostgreSQL at all, and if it is, whether it's failing with an error.

You also appear to be failing to properly check for errors in your PHP code. Use [`pg_result_status`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-status.php) to test for an error, and [`pg_result_status`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-status.php) to get error specifics.

```
$rstation = pg_query($dbconn,$qstation) or die('Query error: ' . pg_last_error());
if (pg_result_status($rstation) != PGSQL_TUPLES_OK) {
    $errmsg = pg_result_error($rstation);
    # ... report error to user or handle it ...
}
```

You might also want to look at [`pg_result_error_field`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-error-field.php) for specific error fields.